# Post Image from one ASP.net Web application1 page to another ASP.Net Webapplication Page and store it in Webapplication2 Image folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created re sized image from image which lies in folder of my ASP.Net web application. temporary i have stored this images into another image folder of my application. But i don't want to store that image into folder. I want to post that image and image name directly to another webpage of different application.

how to do that?

It would be great if some one provides me with solution code on current page(Default.aspx) from which re sized image needs to post and target page(Testreceive.aspx) code...

**Default.aspx** is in My **Webapplication1** and

**TestReceive.aspx** is in my **Webapplication2**

I write code to post Image on source page as below...I am not sure about it.. If it is correct code then how to receive image on target page ???? Here **folder** contains the path of the file in which it lies and **Fname** is name of the image file.

And if it is wrong then please help me to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance..

```
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

                string postImg = folder + Fname;

                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postImg);

                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51399/TestReceive.aspx");

                myRequest.Method = "POST";

                myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

                Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();


                newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                newStream.Close();
```